# How to reset a PS4 controller?

Tags: ps4, controllers

My PS4 controller won't turn on, after holding the reset button for a certain amount of time you have to immediately click a certain button combination to activate your controller without a console. My friend showed me a long time ago but has since passed away and I no longer remember the combination.
Can someone please help me figure out this combination?

Comment: I didn't know PS4 controller had a reset button (and I do still have them in my hand but still can't find the reset button). Is it actually a Dualshock 4? Isn't it third-party controller?

Comment: @Skye-AT it should be that hole on the back, next to the right screw

Comment: Yes it is an actual dualshock 4 controller